# How to make patches transparent?

Tags: netlogo

I have created a tree that are made up by patches in the 2D world. The canopy of tree is green colour. I would want to keep the high density foliage parts green, while low density parts will be still green but with slightly transparent. That would be easy to tell the density on the tree. I know that turtles could be transparent. I am not sure if it is possible to make some green patches slightly transparent. The effects should be just like CSS opacity property (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp). I saw an example from model library, but is for turtles. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? There's nothing underneath patches, so how could they be transparent?

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thank you very much for your reply. I have created a tree that are made up by patches in the 2D world. The canopy of tree is green colour. I would want to keep the high density foliage parts green, while low density parts will be still green but with slightly transparent. That would be easy to tell the density on the tree. I know that turtles could be transparent. I am not sure if it is possible to make some green patches slightly transparent. Thanks.

Comment: I have still have no clue what you mean. Maybe you could add a picture showing what you want? Also, it's better to edit your original question to make it clearer, than to add long comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your response to Seth, it sounds like you are looking for tints of green.  See the NetLogo color scheme: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors  You can choose tints using `scale-color`.  (If you only want tints and not shades, make sure your foliage `density` variable maps to that part of the color range.  E.g., if `density` goes from 0 to 20, then `ask patches [set pcolor scale-color green density 20 -20]`.

Comment: I still believe my answer addresses what you want in the context of patches.  Your transparency reference is not relevant because the white page background is showing through the transparent image. That partial revelation of the white background is what gives the effect you are seeing on that page. But there is no background behind a patch.  (Which is what Seth is saying to you.)

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you very much for your reply. The colour scheme actually has the transparent effects. For example, green = 55, and compared with green, 56 is slightly transparent. That is what I would want. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, for this effect we use the word "tint", not the word "transparency". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades for a discussion. (Also, remember to accept the answer if it met your needs.)